# Can't overwrite prototype method of a base class when using webpack 5

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, pixi.js, webpack-5

I use library PIXI.js in my project & webpack for bundling.
I want to replace a method of some class (Sprite) from PIXI.
Inside PIXI the class is defined like this:

```
var extendStatics$6 = function(d, b) {
        extendStatics$6 = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
                ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
                function (d, b) { for (var p in b) { if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) { d[p] = b[p]; } } };
        return extendStatics$6(d, b);
};

function __extends$6(d, b) {
        extendStatics$6(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
}

var Sprite = (function (_super) {
        __extends$6(Sprite, _super);
        function Sprite(texture) {
                var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
                // some extra initialization logic
        }
        Sprite.prototype.destroy = function (options) {
                // some logic
        };
        return Sprite;
}(Container));
```

I tried to hack it like this:

```
import { Sprite } from 'pixi.js';

console.log(Sprite.prototype, Sprite);
const destroySprite = Sprite.prototype.destroy;
Sprite.prototype.destroy = function (options: any) {
        console.log(this);
        // some extra logic goes here
        destroySprite.call(this, options);
};
```

But the 'patched' method is not being called for Sprite objects.

When debugging, I noticed that when the PIXI loops through some objects that it has to destroy (destroying container with children, among which there are Sprites and other classes, too), it calls destroy method of them and when it encounters Sprite objects - the original destroy method from PIXI is being called. But when it meets some class, that is derived from Sprite - it works fine and the spy method is being called.

Also, just in case if it's useful, when I console.log the Sprite.prototype - I get Container class in the console, but when I print just Sprite - I see it's constructor function.
I think that this may be some issue connected to Webpack, but I'm not sure.

I tried asking in PIXI's forum, but it seems stuck.
Could somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had issues with a previous webpack build myself back in december. It seems the webpack build was pulling from 2 mismatching versions of PIXI at once depending on what I was calling. Your problem seems to be pretty similar. I solved it by migrating my solution to a different bundler / boilerplate, but i'm not sure it will work for you.

I don't 100% understand Webpack, but I think when you build, it must use a CDN or some minimized version of PIXI that is added by looking at the dependencies in the package.json.

You could try to ask on [The Pixi.JS Discord server](https://discord.gg/PsSTPCAr), there are very useful people on there.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply! You are right, it turns out, that in the final bundle.js there are two PIXIs. And I think it's because of ProvidePlugin, that I use.

Comment: UPD: it's not because of ProvidePlugin. It's because of symlink issues when using yarn link. I had to install node_modules in symlinked package for local development - and it was the source of a duplicate PIXI package.